# Can JPA @Converter be used in a Map Mapping using @MapKey?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, openjpa

I am having trouble with Hibernate Map collection mapping where the key is a enum that has a converter that should be attached to it.

**User Role Enumeration with a JPA 2.1 converter**

```
public enum UserRoleDefinition {USER,ADMIN}

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UserRoleDefinitionConverter implements 
             AttributeConverter<UserRoleDefinition, String>
{

  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(UserRoleDefinition attribute)
  {
    return attribute.getName();
  }


  public UserRoleDefinition convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData)
  {
    return UserRoleDefinition.parse(dbData);
  }
}
```

**UserRole Entity non essential attributes removed for clarity**

```
@Entity
public class UserRole 
{
     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_fk")
    private UserAccount userAccount; 

    @Column(name = "role_definition_fk")
    @Convert(converter = UserRoleDefinitionConverter.class)
    private UserRoleDefinition roleDefinition;
}
```

**UserAccount Entity non essential attributes removed for clarity**

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount 
{ 
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "roleDefinition")
    private Map<UserRoleDefinition, UserRole> userRoles = new HashMap<>();
}
```

When I run the application I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: test] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No type name
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.IndexedCollection.validate(IndexedCollection.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1362)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    ... 53 more
```

I have tried all sorts of variations of the mapping, I have traced into the hiberante source code to try to understand why things are not working. In the process I determined that the converter is registered properly with hibernate, and my configuration is correct.

Is the mapping that i want to do above legal in JPA 2.1? if not why not? If yes any idea whats is causing me this problem?

Comment: Looks like validation is trying to figure out the key type and can't.  If you are tracing into source, check if SimpleValue is what it should be using.  You  might try a different provider to see if it is supported, as I don't see why it wouldn't be.

Comment: `@Converter(autoApply = true)` is enough to convert every `UserRoleDefinition` type in your project, so you can remove `@Convert(converter = UserRoleDefinitionConverter.class)` in `roleDefinition` field

Comment: What exactly do `attribute.getName()` and `UserRoleDefinition.parse(dbData)` do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using `UserRoleDefinitionConverter` to persist  `UserRoleDefinition` as string value and get it back as an enum value, so I think it's better to use [@MapKeyEnumerated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) and [@Enumerated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html), so you can remove `UserRoleDefinitionConverter` class and change your code as follows:

**UserRole**

```
@Entity
public class UserRole 
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_fk")
    private UserAccount userAccount; 

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role_definition_fk")
    private UserRoleDefinition roleDefinition;

    //Other stuff...
}
```

**UserAccount**

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount 
{ 
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "roleDefinition")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<UserRoleDefinition, UserRole> userRoles = new HashMap<>();

    //Other stuff...
}
```

**Note:** I know this is an old question, but I hope that it may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Hibernate bug, solved in version 5.0.4.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9475